# Configure kernel driver for Two SC2681 DUARTs

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, serial-port, linux-device-driver

I'm new at kernel development.  I have Lubuntu 12.04 (uname -r == 3.2.0-107-generic) running on a Geode-based PC/104 board.  The CPU does not support PAE, so 12.04 is where I'm at.  There is an I/O board that has two SC2681 DUARTs on it.  They are at ports 0x100 and 0x110 respectvely and both use IRQ 15.

I copied the [sccnxp driver from a newer kernel (3.10)](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/sccnxp.c?v=3.10) and modified it to work under this kernel.  Here is my initialization data:

```
static struct resource sc2681_0_resources[] = {
        DEFINE_RES_IO(0x100, 0x10),
        DEFINE_RES_IRQ(15),
  };

static struct sccnxp_pdata sc2681_0_info = {
        .frequency      = 3686400,
  };

static struct platform_device sc2681_0 = {
    .name       = "sc2681",
    .id     = -1,
    .resource   = sc2681_0_resources,
    .num_resources  = ARRAY_SIZE(sc2681_0_resources),
    .dev = {
        .platform_data  = &sc2681_0_info,
    },
};
```

I also added an __init that contains:

```
platform_device_register(&sc2681_0);
if ((ret = platform_driver_register(&sccnxp_uart_driver)))
{
platform_device_unregister(&sc2681_0);
return -EINVAL;
}
return 0;
```

and an __exit that contains:

```
platform_driver_unregister(&sccnxp_uart_driver);
platform_device_unregister(&sc2681_0);
```

The driver is set up to handle 2 uarts.  This loads and creates /dev/ttySC0 and /dev/ttySC1.  How do I make this load the second DUART at port 0x110?

Comment: You didn't give a clue what the board is (some technical specifications, URL to them). It might be easier way to update Device Tree (ARM), or ACPI (x86) to support them. Also would be nice to see the commits you made on top of existing kernel sources (1. Cloned linux-3.2.y from linux-stable. 2. Pushed non-modified driver. 3. Apply patch to enable it in this kernel.).

Comment: Hi @AndyShevchenko thanks for reading. The duarts are mounted on a custom board that I can't share. I would love to build a kernel, but I have no experience with that yet so for now I've just built sccnxp as a module and loaded it with `insmod`. That part is working but only for the first duart. My question is more about how to set up the resources and platform_device to make the driver load two copies of the devices at two different IO ports.

Comment: You **have to** share any modification to GPL code you did. But let's speak engineer's language. You don't need to share **everything**, just parts related to UART driver.

Comment: Maybe first is good to get familiar with Git and kernel development work flow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question just in case the next reader needs the information.  The answer is that it's only possible if the driver already supports it.

I built a customized kernel off of 4.8 but that cost a lot of time and disk space, and was not the answer.  I still worked in a loadable module because a kernel build and install cycle is long in comparison.  I couldn't find any recent, helpful resources related to x86 device trees and my legacy board doesn't support ACPI.  In short there was no way to "configure" the driver into loading twice for two separate chips.

Having all of the kernel source code, I thought the answer must be somewhere.  I found another serial driver that had similar functionality to what I needed (sb1250-duart.c) and used it as an example.  I changed the probe function to expect and configure multiple chips off of configuration data.  The fault in my original thinking was trying to register two separate platform devices during init, but the solution was to register a single platform device during init and register multiple UART drivers (and ports) in the probe function.

I'd also like to address the GPL comments.  [GNU's GPL FAQ](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#GPLRequireSourcePostedPublic) specifically states that you do not have to release your modified version unless you are releasing any of it to the public, which I am not.  This is purely an in-house project.  However after this experience I do want to share my changes, so after I clean out the company- and platform-specific bits I will push a patch to make this driver support multiple DUARTs.